# s3 sync to replicate whole bucket data + all other s3configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we replicate the whole bucket like its event notification, lifecycle policy, ACL Permission and aother set up from one account to another account in AWS.

I know there is s3 copy(s3 cp) and s3 sync is there but it is only copying data not replicate whole s3 bucket.

we have 50000 buckets in one account we need to replicate all 50000 buckets with data into another AWS account. so it would replicate the whole bucket (data+Confgurations)

Any idea would be really helpful for me.

We did

```
aws s3 sync s3://SOURCE-BUCKET-NAME s3://DESTINATION-BUCKET-NAME --source-region SOURCE-REGION-NAME --region DESTINATION-REGION-NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no commands available to replicate "bucket configurations". You would need to:

- Loop through each source bucket
- Make API calls to discover the configurations
- Make API calls to create the destination buckets and create similar configurations (but be careful -- you probably don't want to replicate things like notifications since they wouldn't be valid in a different account)